# Disqus this.callbacks.onNewComment not working

Tags: javascript, disqus

I somehow cannot get the Disqus this.callbacks.onNewComment to work. What could be wrong? Im trying to alert('hey!') once a new comment is posted. [Source](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/466258-capturing-disqus-commenting-activity-via-callbacks/)

```
<script>
var disqus_config = function () {
this.page.url = PAGE_URL;  
this.page.identifier = PAGE_IDENTIFIER;
    this.callbacks.onNewComment = [function(comment) {
          alert(comment.id);
          alert(comment.text);
          alert('hey!');

    }];
};

(function() {  // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
    var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

    s.src = 'https://example.disqus.com/embed.js';

    s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
    (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `PAGE_URL` and `PAGE_IDENTIFIER` need to be specific to your site
2. This callback is for detecting a new post by this browser window.  Not new posts arriving from other users (or even your own user in another browser windows)

That 2nd one threw me as I thought it was to indicate new post had arrived